# Should questions without an affirmative answer be ignored?

Tags: discussion

Should questions that require omnipotent knowledge to truly answer be ignored, and the lack of answers be the *de facto* answer?

For example, the question "Is there life on Mars?" You can only answer "Yes" if indeed there is life on Mars. If there truly is no life on Mars, nobody is qualified to say that with absolute certainty, as nobody has scoured every inch of the surface looking for it. We can only answer with things like "Nobody has found any yet."

Comment: What is the context of this question?  What RPG.SE question got you thinking along these lines?  I am aware of general guidance that it is OK for a question not to be answered if nobody knows. Questions that are very hard to answer are part of what bounty awards are for.

Comment: My answer to this question got downvoted. To really answer it the answerer will have had to have read every publication by WotC (and know for a fact there are no publications they've missed) to rule out the affirmative. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125986/would-children-age-normally-in-the-outer-planes

Comment: (For what it's worth I'm not bitter about the downvote - it just got me genuinely curious if my speculative answer did not belong and should be deleted.)